# Installed VS Express 2010 with .NET 4.0 and now .NET 3.5 setup project adds 15 dependencies

Tags: .net, installation

I installed VS Express 2010 with .NET 4.0 and now a .NET 3.5 setup project in VS 2008 adds 15 dependencies (below), what is going on???

I did not change anything in the project in between installing VS 2010, VS 2008 is packagin the following files in the project:

====================

Packaging file 'Microsoft.Transactions.Bridge.dll'...

Packaging file 'System.Core.dll'...

Packaging file 'System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'...

Packaging file 'System.Data.Entity.dll'...

Packaging file 'System.Data.Linq.dll'...

Packaging file 'System.Data.Services.Client.dll'...

Packaging file 'System.Data.Services.Design.dll'...

Packaging file 'System.IdentityModel.Selectors.dll'...

Packaging file 'System.IdentityModel.dll'...

Packaging file 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'...

Packaging file 'System.ServiceModel.Web.dll'...

Packaging file 'System.ServiceModel.dll'...

Packaging file 'System.Web.Abstractions.dll'...

Packaging file 'System.Web.Extensions.dll'...

Packaging file 'System.Xml.Linq.dll'...

====================

I've uninstalled VS 2010 and .NET 4.0 but to no avail, same problem.

Lesson learned: DON'T EXPERIMENT ON DEVELOPMENT MACHINE!

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Praise the Lord, got the answer.

I uninstalled .NET 4.0 and when I updated Windows afterwards the .NET 3.5 SP1 update was shown.

I had this update before I installed 4.0.

After I installed the 3.5 SP1 update the problem is gone.

Did not see the 3.5 SP1 update while 4.0 was installed.